# (Mysql + PHP) How to replace a value in every Row in a table

Tags: php, mysql, string, replace

I have the following table:

```
**ID** | **User** | **Password** | **Category**
1      | Test     | PW1          | Cat1
2      | Test2    | PW2          | Cat2
```

I have the following PHP function to change a single value:

```
if($_GET['handler'] == "changerang"){
$ID = $_GET['param2'];  
$NewPW = $_GET['param3'];
$mysqli->query("UPDATE User SET Password='".$NewPW."' WHERE User = '".$ID."'");
echo "success"; 
}
```

That works, but now I want to replace every "Cat" in the entire table in row "Category" with another
string, but I don´t know how to change my function with the Replace function..

Could you help me maybe?

Thank you very much :)
Best regards,
René

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: This look totally unsafe. You should not be storing plain text passwords, but ones hashed and stored using `password_hash()`. I hope that this isn't a live site or going live because you stand at getting hacked, *eventually*. It's just a matter of time really.

Comment: Do you want to replace "cat1" and "cat2" with "feline", or do you want to change them to "feline1" and "feline2". The question isn't clear about what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> now I want to replace every "Cat" in the entire table in row "Category" with another string

Just:

```
update user 
set category = :new_string 
where category like 'Cat%'
```

Important notes: you should be using parameterized queries to make your code safe from sql injection - see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716)

Comment: `USER` is not reserved, it's a keyword https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U - But, `USE` is. See the `(R)`? Two different animals ;-)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE User SET Category = 'NEWCAT' WHERE Category LIKE 'cat%'");
```

Comment: ? Sanity check please ?

Comment: **Note:** On some systems, `Cat` and `cat` are strangely enough and can be two different animals.